# Percona server won't restar after datadir change

Tags: mysql, percona, directory

I installed percona from percona repository on a ubuntu 12.04 server which has a solid state drive. I thought i would rather put the datadir on the Solid state drive and put partition on normal sata drive. below are my settings essentially a copy of my-large.cnf to which i added the datadir and log file in order to see what was failing the starting of the server:

```
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /mnt/disk2/mysqldata
general-log-file= /var/log/mysql.log
log-error       = /var/log/mysql-error.log
skip-external-locking
```

after enabling the log i'm seeing :

```
130127 11:49:07 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /mnt/disk2/mysqldata/servername.pid ended
130127 12:07:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /mnt/disk2/mysqldata
130127 12:07:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
130127 12:07:55 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130127 12:07:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130127 12:07:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130127 12:07:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130127 12:07:55 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130127 12:07:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130127 12:07:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130127 12:07:55 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130127 12:07:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130127 12:07:56 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 1.1.8-rel29.3 started; log   sequence number 1597945
130127 12:07:56 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130127 12:07:56 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130127 12:07:56 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130127 12:07:56 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
130127 12:07:56 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /mnt/disk2/mysqldata/servername.pid ended
130127 12:08:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /mnt/disk2/mysqldata
/usr/sbin/mysqld: File './mysql-bin.~rec~' not found (Errcode: 13)
130127 12:08:50 [ERROR] MYSQL_BIN_LOG::open_purge_index_file failed to open register  file.
130127 12:08:50 [ERROR] MYSQL_BIN_LOG::open_index_file failed to sync the index file.
130127 12:08:50 [ERROR] Aborting

130127 12:08:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130127 12:23:41 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130127 12:23:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /mnt/disk2/mysqldata/servername.pid ended
130127 18:06:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /mnt/disk2/mysqldata
130127 18:06:57 [Warning] The syntax '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--general-log'/'--general-log-file' instead.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: File './mysql-bin.~rec~' not found (Errcode: 13)
130127 18:06:57 [ERROR] MYSQL_BIN_LOG::open_purge_index_file failed to open register  file.
130127 18:06:57 [ERROR] MYSQL_BIN_LOG::open_index_file failed to sync the index file.
130127 18:06:57 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I thought it was permission issues or i should copy data from `/var/lib/mysql` to the new folder but now that I could make the log generated am not sure about what to do.

Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEver mind , i copied the files from /var/lib/mysql to the new location.